# Hyperlink is not clickable in gmail

Tags: html, hyperlink, gmail, html-email

I tried to put a HTML hyperlink like this

```
<a href="test-app://param=123">Click here</a>
```

in my HTML email template and sent it using java mail library. When I open that email in my gmail, it displays "Click here" but the link is not clickable. It's just <a>Click here</a> (the part "href="test-app://param=123" is removed). It works well when I replace the link in href by the links like www.google.com. 


Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop Gmail from stripping the values out of URLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666796/how-do-i-stop-gmail-from-stripping-the-values-out-of-urls)

Comment: I tried the solution in that thread already but it does not work :(

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and in my case I hadn't explicitly given the protocol so I just added `http://`to all my urls and it worked fine after that. In your example your url looks strange too though.

I would imagine you would have to have something like

```
<a href="http://test-app?param=123">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define your own schema in the AppManifest.

Take a look here:

[Hyperlinks with non HTTP schema in GMAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186235/hyperlinks-with-non-http-schema-in-gmail)