# Use url-schema as href value in gmail

Tags: gmail, strip, url-scheme

I am trying to insert a url-schema as the href attribute value in an email but when the email arrives, the href has been removed from gmail and hence the button is not clickable.

If I put a normal link with the http(s) protocol I don't have any problem. I found some similar questions as: [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416676/preventing-gmail-from-stripping-href-target-and-id-attributes), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666796/how-do-i-stop-gmail-from-stripping-the-values-out-of-urls), but there isn't a solution.

There is a method to prevent that behavior?